# HTML Table with Pagination and Stay the Pagination Below Even the Table Data is empty

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to set the pagination much more lower the table regardless its minimum height. I'm using bootstrap. My current issue is that, when the data is empty or let say, it's around 3 item only, the pagination is just below the table. What I want to achieve is something like this:

[image]

I'm using bootstrap, here's my sample table: https://jsfiddle.net/wrkaut1x/5/

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
<th>Header 1</th>
<th>Header 2</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>No data</td>    
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div>
<p>
Pagination here..
</p>
</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I hope somebody can help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try adding a min-height to the table? like `min-height: 400px` then the table will cover 400px and the pagination will be shown below that.